# Escape Column names writing to SQL with python,pyodbc from csv

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pyodbc

I am a pretty new to coding and am stuck. I am pulling a report through an api which gives me a .csv file. I want to paste this into a SQL database but am running into some trouble.

My current code looks like this:

reader is the decoded csv file.

```
columns = next(reader,None)
query = "INSERT INTO table({0}) VALUES ({1})"
query = query.format(','.join(columns),','.join('?'*len(columns)))
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, columns)
for data in reader:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
cursor.commit()
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'.
>   (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I think the issue is that my columns are:

```
Date |  Advertiser |    Campaign |  Ad Group | etc.
```

And it seems that maybe SQL is recognizing the "Group" of "Ad Group" as a variable.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It's not that it's recognising it as a variable - it's that it can't interpret it because of the space in the column name. You'd need to put a column name like that in square brackets for sql server to interpret it (and in general it's a good idea to encase all your column names in square brackets anyway) - so instead of `insert into table(date, advertiser, campaign, ad group)` it should be `insert into table([date], [advertiser], [campaign], [ad group])`

Comment: @ZLK Thank you so much. That worked. Now it looks like my data is coming through as a string "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." Is there a quick fix for that as well by any chance?

Comment: Um, it depends on what your data looks like. What does the date field look like?

Comment: The date field is formatted as 8/23/2017.

Comment: It might be an issue with the default date format for SQL. A quick fix _might_ be to have `SET DATEFORMAT MDY;` before your insert.

Comment: Dang not quite. If I go directly to the query editor and enter 
INSERT INTO Point_It_RTB ([Date]) Values (8/21/2017)
That works.
Looking at the print out I am seeing:
['08/28/2017', 'Advertiser1', 'campaign1','adgroup1']
Do I need to remove those ' ' somehow?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a comment by @ZLK you need to enclose the column names in square brackets. This will do the trick:

```
query = query.format('[{0}]'.format('], ['.join(columns)),','.join('?'*len(columns)))
```

Comment: This will only work if your column names do not themselves contain square brackets.  If you want to be safer, you'll need to also replace `]` with `]]` in your dynamic column names before wrapping them in square brackets.  This will prevent SQL injection AND allow you to have bona fide brackets in column names.